# What it means when as is added in front of an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

What does it mean when "as" is added in front of an adjective? For example:

> Although colors may not be **as** important to consumers, we are of the opinion that having more variety will increase sales.

Why wasn't it just:

> ***Although colors may not be <del>as</del> important to consumers ...*** ?

Comment: Because it implies "as important *as something else*", which may or may not be stated elsewhere.

Comment: Do you understand the use of "as" for comparison, like in, "*It's **as** hot as an oven outside*"?

Comment: Would be good if you gave a link for context.

Comment: Please  state the source of quotes used in ELL questions (and answers), giving author, title, and publication, with a link if  at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "as" here indicates a comparison.

> Although colors may not be as important to consumers, ...

means that colors are less important to consumers than something else, but are still not unimportant. What else is more important is not stated in the quoted text. It might be in a longer excerpt.